# Model retraining

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, random-forest, decision-trees, data-science-model

I trained my model with `RandomForestRegressor()`, but now my training data is updated continuously. So I have to train my model with all the train data set i.e past and new data, or can I directly train my model only with new data? But if I train model only with new data, will it keep the pattern in existing data or not?

Comment: Tree-based models are not trained in an Incremental way.

Comment: That has already been explained in the answer (not all algos accept that approach by default)

Answer (score 0):

For sure you have to **make sure your final model has seen all the history training dataset some time** . 
The only chance you have is to retrain your model (and not all the training algorithms accept it) in the fashion of **incremental learning**, where an already trained model is updated by being exposed to the new incoming data (used in online learning for instance), but **it does not mean to completely retrain your model only on new data**. In case you need it, have a look at it: https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning  where decision trees are not actually included for incremental learning

In your case, I recommend you (in case you can deal with performance cost) to retrain with all your available dataset.